# Does the SDK for AWS personalize work with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, aws-sdk

I'm setting up a web client in a ruby on rails application inside a docker container and I want it to use the Amazon Personalize SDK. The documentation is written for Python and the AWS CLI. I'm writing a sample request in ruby using the Net::HTTP library and running into problems.

Currently my request is returning a 403 and a `<InvalidSignatureException>
  <Message>Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'personalize'. </Message>` error. I think my problem is I'm not using the right `host`

But, when I bundle the `aws-sdk` gem, I see many `aws-sdk` gems being bundled that look like `aws-sdk-#{name_of_aws_service}`, but no `aws-sdk-personalize`. So my question is, why is this? Am I barking up the wrong tree by trying to do this with Ruby? Do I need to learn Python?

```rb
host = # removed because SO
service = 'es'
region = '' #removed because SO

signer = Aws::Sigv4::Signer.new(
  service: service,
  region: region,
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)
document = {
  # removed because SO
}

signature = signer.sign_request(
  http_method: 'PUT',
  url: host,
  body: document.to_json
)

uri = URI(host)

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => true) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Put.new uri
  request.body = document.to_json
  request['Host'] = signature.headers['host']
  request['X-Amz-Date'] = signature.headers['x-amz-date']
  request['X-Amz-Security-Token'] = signature.headers['x-amz-security-token']
  request['X-Amz-Content-Sha256']= signature.headers['x-amz-content-sha256']
  request['Authorization'] = signature.headers['authorization']
  request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  response = http.request request
  puts response.code
  puts response.body
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I got from a close read of the documentation was no. And AWS Personalize isn't for general release anyway. So I'm going to mark this as solved and move on.

Answer (score 0):

The another solution is to use this gem, let's say you have key id, secret key and session token

https://github.com/winebarrel/faraday_middleware-aws-sigv4

```
conn = Faraday.new(url: API_BASE_URL) do |faraday|
    faraday.request :aws_signers_v4,
         credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(response["access_key_id"], response["secret_key"], response["session_token"]),
          service_name: 'execute-api',
          region: 'us-east-1'
  faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end
puts conn.headers
response = conn.post('/orders') do |req|
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
end
puts response.body
```